# echo .[!.]* displays an event not found error

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, kali-linux

is there a problem with my Linux distribution?
i tried to run this command using the ! symbol,but it always display an error:

```
echo .[!.]*  
zsh: event not found: .
```

Am using Kali Linux.

Comment: As alternative to the solution given by chepner: If you don't plan to use history expansion at all, you can also (in your .zshrc) turn it off by `setopt nobanghist` and then don't need to worry about escaping the `!`.

Answer (score 3):

Either escape the `!`

```
echo .[\!.]*
```

or use `^` instead

```
echo .[^.]*
```

Both avoid unintentionally triggering history expansion.

Comment: thanks alot. ^ works